# How to actually apply martingales when conditioning on a random variable (not filtration)?

Tags: probability, martingale

For a Galton-Watson process, I've shown that $\frac{Z_n}{\mu^n}$ is a martingale i.e. $E[\frac{Z_{n+1}}{\mu^{n+1}}|\mathcal{F}_n]=\frac{Z_n}{\mu^n}$.

However, I want to show that, for $n>m$,
$$E[Z_{n}|Z_m]=\mu^{n-m}Z_m.$$
But I don't understand how to compute the right-hand side using the knowledge that $\frac{Z_n}{\mu^n}$ is a martingale. I have been messing around with it for a little while, but I can't reach it.

Comment: Use induction on $n-m.$

Comment: @whuber Apply induction how? I find that $E[Z_{n+1}|F_n]=\mu Z_n$, does $E[Z_{n+1}|Z_n]=\mu Z_n$? And then $E[Z_{n+2}|Z_n]=\mu Z_{n+1}$? Then what?

Comment: @whuber what about: 
$$E[Z_{n}|Z_m] = E[E[Z_{n}|Z_{n-1}] |Z_m] = E[ \mu Z_{n-1} |Z_m] = E[E[Z_{n-1}|Z_{n-2}] |Z_m] = E[ \mu^{2}Z_{n-2} |Z_m] = ... =
\mu^{n-m}Z_m$$ 
(the "..." repeated until reaching $Z_m$)